# Tools for investigating the convergence of the improper integral $\int_0^1\cos(1/x)\mathrm dx$ and similar integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I am struggling to see why the integral 
$$
\int_0^1 \cos(1/x)\mathrm dx
$$

Is convergent and why for example 
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\cos(1/x)\mathrm dx
$$
Is only conditionally convergent.

My usual tools like taylor expansion, investigating the limit of the integrand multiplied by $x^p$ (quotient test) don't apply. Furthermore, I am not sure how to tackle the limit since these Is there something clever I can bound these integrals below by?

I have been able to see why 
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}\cos(1/x)\mathrm dx
$$
Is divergent, since that has an elementary antiderivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be the integral given by

$$I=\int_0^1 \cos(1/x)\,dx \tag 1$$

Now, enforcing the substitution $x\to 1/x$ in $(1)$ yields

$$I=\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx \tag 2$$

Since the integral in $(2)$ absolutely converges, it converges.  Therefore, the integral in $(1)$ converges.

Comment: gah I don't know why I missed this. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

If $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is bounded and $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,1]$ for $0< a <1,$ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1].$ This shows$\int_0^1 \cos (1/x)$ converges.

Comment: Thank you for the good fact I didn't know.

Comment: You're welcome. The result is useful and not too hard to prove.